# How can I compile CUDA code then link it to a C++ project?

Tags: cuda, g++, nvcc

I am looking for help getting started with a project involving CUDA. My goal is to have a project that I can compile in the native g++ compiler but uses CUDA code. I understand that I have to compile my CUDA code in nvcc compiler, but from my understanding I can somehow compile the CUDA code into a cubin file or a ptx file.

Here are my questions:

1. How do I use nvcc to compile into a cubin file or a ptx file? Don't I need a -c or something?
2. Which file type do I want to use?
3. What are the g++ commands to correctly compile and link the project together?

Assume the following:

1. I have a file called "main.cpp" that has a main function in it and includes cuda.h.
2. I have another file called "cudaFunc.cu" that has CUDA code in it. Let's say, for instance, that I want to add two integer arrays that exist in main.cpp.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with a couple of different posts including these ones. Don't forget that if you are using a 64 bit machine to link to the 64 bit library! It seams kind of obvious, but for clowns like me, that is something I forgot. Here is the make file that I now use... if you can digest this make file, you should be able to do what I was trying to do which was separate compilation of cuda code and other G++ code. Also keep in mind that you have to have the gcc, g++ compilers at certain versions (I am using g++-4.4 and it is working for me) Anyway, here is the make file...

```
all: program

program: cudacode.o
    g++ -o program -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart main.cpp  cudacode.o 

cudacode.o:
    nvcc -c -arch=sm_20 cudacode.cu 

clean: rm -f *.o program
```

Hopefully you can see that the first thing I do is compile the cudacode (that has been saved as a `.cu`) using the `nvcc` compiler and `-c` option (also note that you may want to remove the `-arch=sm_20`). This created a `cudacode.o`. I then use the g++ compiler with the `-o` option and link to the lib64 library and link the `-lcuda` and `-lcudart` libraries along with compiling my `main.cpp` and then linking the `cudacode.o`. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Can you also provide a minimal `.cu` and `.cpp` files you tested with? Curious about the includes used, cpp, in particular how to see the kernel `__global__` functions from `.cu`.

Comment: Careful there, your clean target will remove all files ending with 'o'. You probably want `clean: rm -rf *.o program`

Comment: I'm getting mangled names in the generated object files (for the function that I need to call from my non-`.cu` file).  Anyone have an idea how to fix that up?

Comment: How can I write this using automake?

Comment: Just because I had some issues with this myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811539/can-i-call-cuda-runtime-function-from-c-code-not-compiled-by-nvcc/75843299#75843299 this SO post has more detail on how you can call CUDA-functions from cpp files.

Answer (score 17):

My answer [to this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363827/building-gpl-c-program-with-cuda-module) likely describes what you need.

A couple of additional notes:

1. You don't need to compile your `.cu` to a `.cubin` or `.ptx` file.  You need to compile it to a `.o` object file and then link it with the `.o` object files from your .cpp files compiled with g++.
2. In addition to putting your cuda kernel code in `cudaFunc.cu`, you also need to put a C or C++ wrapper function in that file that launches the kernel (unless you are using the CUDA driver API, which is unlikely and not recommended). Also add a header file with the prototype of this wrapper function so that you can include it in your C++ code which needs to call the CUDA code. Then you link the files together using your standard g++ link line.

Comment: Harrism, Thank you for your answer. I am much closer now. I can compile just fine using the nvcc compiler and the .cu file (which I renamed to cudacode.cu) and I have a cudacode.o object, but now when I try to compile on the g++ I get cudacode.o: In function `wrapper(int*, int*, int*, int)':
tmpxft_00000d3a_00000000-1_cudacode.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'

Comment: You need to link libcudart.  First figure out where libcudart.so is -- by default I think it goes into /usr/local/bin/cuda, but that varies by installation.  Once you find the path, add this to your link line: `-L<path to CUDA libs> -lcudart`.

Comment: you are my hero! thank you. an additional issue i was having was that i am on a 64 bit machine, so i had to link to the lib64 file. just three hours ago i didnt know how to use g++, i didn't know what a make file was, and i didnt know how to link. i guess that is what i get for growing up on windows.

Answer (score 12):

I found that linking the compiled cuda object code with g++ can be troublesome.
Try compiling it like this:

```
all:
nvcc cudafile.cu mainfile.cpp -o executable

clean: rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: I'd use rm -f rather than rm -rf, because the *.o files should be regular files and I'm scared of making a fatal error: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/01/17/scary_code_of_the_week_steam_cleans_linux_pcs/

Comment: @Adam P. Goucher If on Ubuntu, you can install `safe-rm` :)